calculating a normal derivative
let $\mathcal{G}(x, y),(x, y) \in \overline{B_R} \times B_R$
be the following function $\mathcal{G}(x, y)=\frac{1}{4 \pi|x-y|}-\frac{R|y|}{\left||y|^2 x-R^2 y\right|} .$
$\begin{aligned}
&\text { let }|y|=r \text { and let } \theta \text { the angle between teh vectors} x \text { and } y \text {. then }\\
&\begin{aligned}
& \mathcal{G}(x, y)=\frac{1}{4 \pi \sqrt{|x|^2+r^2-2 r|x| \cos \theta}}-\frac{R r}{4 \pi \sqrt{r^4|x|^2+R^4 r^2-2 R^2 r^3|x| \cos \theta}} \\
& =\frac{1}{4 \pi \sqrt{|x|^2+r^2-2 r|x| \cos \theta}}-\frac{R}{4 \pi \sqrt{r^2|x|^2+R^4-2 R^2 r|x| \cos \theta}}
\end{aligned}
\end{aligned}$
the normal derivative is
$\frac{\partial \mathcal{G}}{\partial n}(x, y)=\frac{\partial}{\partial r}\left[\frac{1}{4 \pi \sqrt{r^2+|x|^2-2 r|x| \cos \theta}}-\frac{R}{4 \pi \sqrt{r^2|x|^2+R^4-2 R^2 r|x| \cos \theta}}\right]_{r=R}$
my quesion I know that  $\frac{\partial \mathcal{G}}{\partial n}(x, y)=\nabla\mathcal{G} \hat{n}$ but I don't understand why in the gradient we calculate only the derivative respect to $r$ when my function is both dependent on $y,\theta$

Hint: the gradient was not calculated, the dot product $\nabla G\cdot\hat{n}$ was. What does that say about $\hat{n}$?
